# playframework 2.0 streaming audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, playframework, playframework-2.0

So im using playframework 2.0 and I am successfully streaming audio using the following code on the server:

```
public static Result recording() {
    File wavFile = new File("C:\\test.wav");
    return ok(wavFile);
}
```

And this works fine.

the problem i have is that it changes to a new page. I would like it instead to open up a little dialog box maybe, or create a new surrounding div.
So I figure I have to create an ajax request, and I can create a a new div but im not sure what to do with the successful data object. Any examples would be really helpful I havent been able to find any:

```
$('#sound').click( function(evt) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  jQuery("#sound").attr("href"),
                data: jQuery("#sound").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                            //What do i need to do here
                    alert('Call history download');
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    setError('Call history download failed');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [html5 <audio> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<audio src="@routes.MyController.recording()" controls autoplay loop>  
   <p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>  
</audio>
```

If you want to start the sound with javascript, you can skip all the ajax stuff, and just add a  element using javascript/jQuery. Then the sound should start automatically.

Note, that wave files are not supported by IE (figures!!). IE 9 only supports MP3. But Firefox and Opera does not support MP3. To support multiple file formats, you can do something like this:

```
<audio controls autoplay loop>  
   <source src="@routes.MyController.recordingWave()" type="audio/wave" />
   <source src="@routes.MyController.recordingMp3()" type="audio/mp3" />
   <p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>  
</audio>
```

Comment: Ok so I ended up using the audio tag you gave me and it works pretty nicely in chrome but wouldn't show up in firefox.

Comment: It should work in Firefox! You might have to supply severel audio formats, since browsers don't agree on which formats to support. I found this browser compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#section_6